# Can't get text appearing with javascript .appendChild

Tags: javascript

This is the append function I'm using

```js
function append(parent, el) {
  return parent.appendChild(el);
}
```

And this is where it's being used

```
let container = document.getElementById("container");
let line = createNode("p");
let line2 = createNode("p");
let line3 = createNode("p");
line.innerHTML = data[key][0];
line2.innerHTML = data[key][1];
//this line checks if there is a third type to be displayed
if (typeof data[key][2] !== "undefined") {
  line3.innerHTML = data[key][2];
}
append(container, line);
append(container, line2);
append(container, line3);
```

The console error always comes back as `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')`
Which part of the appendChild is null?

Comment: your `container` (via `document.getElementById`) is `null`

Comment: Are you sure it's an ID and not a class?

Comment: Got some HTML that goes with this code?

Comment: What is `createNode`?